# Как удалить ключ из словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Создал словарь `аа` таким образом:

```
aa = {}
```

После чего добавил в него ключ, вот так:

```
aa['category', 'title:викенд'] = {}
```

В результате, при выводе словаря получаю:

```
{('category', 'title:викенд'): {}}
```

Какие есть способы удалить этот ключ из словаря `aa`, чтобы в результате я получил словарь без этого ключа?

Пытался удалить с помощью `del products['category', f'title:викенд']`, также c помощью `products.pop['category', f'title:викенд']`, но получал ошибки.

Comment: `del products[('category', f'title:викенд')]`, `_ = products.pop[('category', f'title:викенд')]`

Comment: Возникает ошибка

Comment: у меня почему-то ошибка не возникает - смотрите примеры в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вариант 1:

```
In [230]: products = {}

In [231]: products['category', 'title:викенд'] = {}

In [232]: del products[('category', f'title:викенд')]

In [233]: products
Out[233]: {}
```

#### Вариант 2:

```
In [234]: products = {}

In [235]: products['category', 'title:викенд'] = {}

In [236]: products
Out[236]: {('category', 'title:викенд'): {}}

In [237]: _ = products.pop(('category', f'title:викенд'))

In [238]: products
Out[238]: {}
```

---

Если хотите разобраться почему так происходит:

```
In [239]: x = 'category', 'title:викенд'

In [240]: type(x)
Out[240]: tuple

In [241]: print(x)
('category', 'title:викенд')
```

Т.е. если написать несколько значений через запятую, не указывая явно тип и без скобок, то получим кортеж (`tuple`).

Answer (score 1):

А в чём проблема?

У вас же в словаре только 1 элемент, у которого ключ `('category', 'title:викенд')`

Значит и удалить вы его можете так:

```
del aa['category', 'title:викенд']
```

или так:

```
aa.pop(('category', 'title:викенд'))
```

или вы хотели кодом

```
aa['category', 'title:викенд'] = {}
```

создать 2 элемента с ключами `'category'` и `'title:викенд'`?

тогда это скорее так должно было бы выглядеть:

```
aa = {'category': {}, 'title:викенд': {}}

del aa['category']
```